# Erro quando count() menor que 1

Tags: php

Tenho um código que verifica quantos registros uma consulta sql retorna.

```
<?php
if ($results) { $total = count($results); }
if ($total > 0) {
  echo "<p>Encontramos " .count($results). " conteúdo(s) para a sua busca!</p>";
} else {
  echo "<p>Lamentamos mas nenhum conteúdo foi encontrado para a sua busca! Tente novamente...</p>";
}
?>
```

Quando encontra 1 ou mais registros a mensagem ao usuário aparece certinho. Quando nada é encontrado ou seja `count() = 0` aparece o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: total in D:\xampp\htdocs\armazemdahouse\publication.php on line 164
>       Lamentamos mas nenhum conteúdo foi encontrado para a sua busca! Tente novamente...

Como soluciono?

Comment: Qual o código que está na linha `164` do `publication.php` ?. E como está a ser construído o `$results`?

Comment: @Isac a linha 164 é if ($total > 0) {

Answer (score 2):

Bom Flávio. 
Eu faria algo assim!

```html
public function verificaResultados($lista){
     if(isset($lista)){
       $total_results = count($lista);
       if($total_results <= 0){
         echo "nada encontrado";
       }else{
         echo "$lista";// ;D
        }
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele não encontra a variável $total porque ele não entra no if onde se encontra o "$results" e não inicializa o "$total".

Então antes eu verifico se a variável "$results" existe e se ele também é um array para poder ser contado.

```
<?php
if(isset($results)){
    $total = 0;
    if (is_array($results)) { 
        $total = count($results); 
    }else{
        $total = 1;
    }
    if ($total > 0) {
        echo "<p>Encontramos " .count($results). " conteúdo(s) para a sua busca!</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Lamentamos mas nenhum conteúdo foi encontrado para a sua busca! Tente novamente...</p>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<p>Lamentamos mas nenhum conteúdo foi encontrado para a sua busca! Tente novamente...</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: quando count() menor que 1 a váriavel não é setada correto, deve ser esse o eerro então.

Comment: Exatamente isso que acontece.